# Implementing my own FFT in MATLAB giving wrong results

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to implement my own fft in MATLAB the following way:

```
function z=FastFourierTransform(x)
  N=length(x);
  if N <= 1
    z = x;
  else
    range = (0:N/2-1);
    e = exp(-2i*pi/N).^range;
    odd = FastFourierTransform(x(1:2:N-1));
    even = e.*FastFourierTransform(x(2:2:N));
    z = [even + odd, even - odd];
  end
return
```

Turns out, there seems to be somthing wrong with it since it does not give the same result as the built in function provided by MATLAB.

I'm calling the function the following way:

```
N = 128;
x = 32*pi*(1:N)'/N;
u = cos(x/16).*(1+sin(x/16));
actualSolution = fft(u);
actualSolution
mySolution = FastFourierTransform(u)';
mySolution
```

[actualSolution](https://pastebin.com/NCTd9pwv)

[mySolution](https://pastebin.com/JPX9ag9p)

The numbers are always the same but they sometimes differ in their sign.

Comment: Besides the issue pointed out by Aziz, you have a second error: `'` is the complex conjugate transpose. When you do `FastFourierTransform(u)'`, you are not only changing the orientation of your vector, you are also changing the sign of all imaginary components. Use `.'` for the transpose.

Answer (score 2):

You have swapped odd and even.

Using this line to compute `z` will produce the correct FFT:

```
z = [odd + even, odd - even];
```

My guess is that the source of confusion is that Matlab uses 1-based indices, and the pseudocode you used to implement the function uses 0-based indices.